# Kivy regarding Label Background colours

Tags: label, kivy, background-color

I am new to Kivy. Currently i have problem, i want to have a Label with Background colours. I wrote these code but it seems that the Label of the background colour is still displaying black. 
May I know if there is any other solution to resolve this issue?

```
label = Label(text='test',pos=(20, 20),size=(180, 100),size_hint=(None,None))
with label.canvas:
    Color(0, 1, 0, 0.25)
    Rectangle(pos=label.pos, size=label.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it, is by using my own label `MyLabel`

In the `.py`

```py
class MyLabel(Label):
    pass
```

In the `.kv:`

```
<MyLabel>:
    back_color: .1, .1, .1, 1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: root.back_color
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
```

After that, you can just do:

```
a_label = MyLabel()
a_label.back_color = [1, 0, 1, 1]
```

Comment: desc = Label(
     text = '[b]'+ item[1] +'[/b]' + '\n\n' + 'Mcdonald', 
     markup= True, 
     font_size='15sp', 
     size_hint=(1, 0), 
     halign="left", 
     valign="top",
     )                                                            Hmm so how i do write it if i have a Label ^, this is in under one of the class (screen) i've created.

Comment: @KelvinWongWeiLiang `desc.back_color = [1, 0, 1, 1]`? What exactly you don't understand?